# Setting up /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, network-manager, dns

I am setting up a connection to Optimum business with a static ip

- Ip address 47.x.x.62
- Default gateway 47.x.x.61
- subnet mask 255.255.255.252
- Primary DNS server 167.x.x.138
- Seconday DNS Server 167.x.x.4

I am trying to set up eth0 (eno1) to be on the static IP
and eth1 (eno2) to be on the network (LAN)
eno2 is up and working but eno1 is not.

I don't seem to be getting to commands to set up to the name server correct
any suggestions?

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp
iface eno1 inet static
    address 47.x.x.62
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    gateway 47.x.x.61

# The primary network interface
auto eno2
#iface eno2 inet dhcp
iface eno2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: this is for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: eno2 is supposed to be statis as well? Are you sure the gateway is accepting static ips?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I don't seem to be getting to commands to set up to the name server correct' ? what name server?

Comment: on my optimun business account i have to set up IP subnet gateway and primary/secondary dns server to access it

Comment: the exact problem is I want eno1 directly to the internet and Its not on the net

Comment: eno1 is set to static because Optimum business requires it
eno2 is also set to static because i want it on the same LAN ip which is shut of from the WWW

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but in case you want to set custom DNS you can do it in few ways.

1. add `dns-nameservers {IP}` to your interfaces file.
2. or add `nameserver {IP}` to `/etc/resolv.conf` (this is not permanent solution).

Comment: when i put dns-nameservers in on ifconfig I get host name lookup failure